# AdMob does not refresh the Ads

Tags: android, admob

Here is my AdView

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId=""
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
/>
```

On Admob website, I have set 'Automatic Refresh' to 'Refresh Rate: 22 sec'.

Here is LogCat output:

```
12-10 11:59:20.757: I/Ads(30363): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script .......

12-10 11:59:22.296: I/Ads(30363): Received ad url: <"url":  ..... 

12-10 11:59:47.085: I/Ads(30363): Refreshing ad.

12-10 11:59:47.390: I/Ads(30363): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script ...........

12-10 11:59:48.339: I/Ads(30363): Received ad url: <"url": ..... 

12-10 11:59:49.394: I/Ads(30363): onReceiveAd()

12-10 12:00:09.276: I/Ads(30363): Refreshing ad.

12-10 12:00:09.558: I/Ads(30363): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script ...... 

12-10 12:00:10.046: I/Ads(30363): Received ad url: <"url":  ...... 

12-10 12:00:11.448: I/Ads(30363): onReceiveAd()
12-10 12:00:31.463: I/Ads(30363): Refreshing ad.

12-10 12:00:31.558: I/Ads(30363): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script ....... 

12-10 12:00:32.085: I/Ads(30363): Received ad url: <"url":  .......... 

12-10 12:00:33.191: I/Ads(30363): onReceiveAd()
```

Although LogCat shows that AdMob refreshes Ads but the same Add (the Add which was loaded very first time) is shown on the device.

Is there anything needs to be done on Java side.

**UPDATE**

**Advertise.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.becomputer06.vehicle.diary.free"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId=""
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidMenifest**

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.becomputer06.vehicle.diary.free"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0.1.FREE">
           ........
</manifest>
```

The result of the code listed above (Compilation Errors):-

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package 'com.becomputer06.vehicle.diary.free' advertise.xml   /vehicle-diary-free/res/layout  line 5  Android AAPT Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adUnitId' in package 'com.becomputer06.vehicle.diary.free'   advertise.xml   /vehicle-diary-free/res/layout  line 5  Android AAPT Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'loadAdOnCreate' in package 'com.becomputer06.vehicle.diary.free' advertise.xml   /vehicle-diary-free/res/layout  line 5  Android AAPT Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Comment: I find it intriguing that even though your refresh rate is 45s, your logs seem to suggest a refresh rate of about half of that.  Do you have two AdViews in your application by any chance?

Comment: it's a typo. the refresh rate is 22 sec

Answer (score 3):

I am making the assumption here that you include your actual adUnitId in your XML definition.  Otherwise you wouldn't be receiving ads.

Note that you're in test mode.  By specifying `ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"`, you're asking the emulator to send you test ads.  When you request an ad in test mode, you will get the same ad back every time.  Try removing that parameter, or better yet try debugging on your device, and see if you get a different result.

Comment: I added the actual unit id when I was testing it on Galaxy I9000; it displays the same advertise on a particular activity/screen even if I the screen stays "onfocus" for 5 minutes.

Comment: That's odd.  Can you provide a description or image of what the ad looks like?  Also, have you still been getting the same ad when debugging over the course of the last two days?

Comment: No, I get different ads like download Opera, 'Make desire faster and Safer' etc.

Comment: So if you are getting different ads, then isn't it refreshing?

Comment: Actual problem is:- I opened activity/screen; AdMob displayed the advertise; I stayed on the same activity/screen for 5 minutes; AdMob did not refresh the advertise (show different advertise).

Comment: Apologies, but I still don't understand.  You are saying that you stayed on the same screen for 5 minutes and AdMob did NOT show different advertisements?

Comment: i misunderstood the concept .... the ad was refreshing itself but it was showing same ad.... :)

Comment: Glad it makes sense now.  Yeah, when you're in test mode, you're going to get the same test ad every time :)

Comment: @EricLeichtenschlag seems like Admob is keep on loading same ad? may be got short of ads! isn't it :? ;)

Comment: @MuhammadBabar It depends on inventory available, location, time of day, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In the Admob website i think you have register your application by giving the package name. After that you need to take the publisher id from the website and give it in the adUnitId in the xml .

In the java code:

```
    AdView adview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
    re.setGender(AdRequest.Gender.FEMALE); 
    adview.loadAd(re);
```

In the xml:

```
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.xxxx" (com.xxx---> your application package name)
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        android:background="#4876FF"
        ads:adUnitId=" "

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the Admob website, go to settings and change the refresh rate to 12 seconds.
Please click this option also "Use Google ads and Google certified ad networks to improve fill rate". I think this will clear you problem

In the res folder--->under "values" you need to add new xml named attrs.xml  In that you need to add

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <resources>
     <declare-styleable name="com.google.ads.AdView">
     <attr name="adSize">
       <enum name="BANNER" value="1"/>
       <enum name="IAB_MRECT" value="2"/>
       <enum name="IAB_BANNER" value="3"/>
       <enum name="IAB_LEADERBOARD" value="4"/>
    </attr>
    <attr name="adUnitId" format="string"/>
   </declare-styleable>
   </resources>
```

Comment: This code gives compilations errors. Checkout the UPDATE part in question. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm fairly certain this package definition is the old way of doing things (back before v4.1.0 of the AdMob SDK when you had to define attrs.xml).  With 4.1.0 and up, the SDK now has these attributes bundled with the SDK, so you should stick with `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.google.ads"`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem..updating the admob SDK to the latest version resolved the issue